# Can we do mobile automation directly with Ruby without cucumber?

Tags: android, ios, ruby, cucumber

I am a newbie to mobile test automation.  I searched a bit and read a lot about using calabash (cucumber + ruby) to automate the testing for Android and iOS.

If we don't use the cucumber layer in between (i.e. if we don't have cross functional teams), is it possible to do mobile test automation for android or iOS directly with the programming language through Eclipse/Rubymine?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think cucumber layer is between something. Its the front end using which you write the feature and scenarios. I have been using Calabash for both android and ios automation testing and I do not think it can work without cucumber. But there are cases where people try to use Java or C# instead of Ruby with cucumber. Here is the github link https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke. It looks old and i am not sure if there is active development on cuke4duke